# Array with chars in c

Tags: c

I'm all new to C and just wanted to try some programming for fun! My first idea was to create a Tic-Tac-Toe game. In the following code I'm trying to generate a field. It works to some degree, but when I test it the entries `feld[1][0]` and `feld[2][0]` are empty. Also Something I dont understand is, if I save more then one letter in an entry, for example xx, it apears somewhere else. I'm guessings it's a problem with the saveing space assignment of C. Glad for any feedback!

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
  int i,j;
  char feld[3][3];
  for(j=0; j<3; j++)
  {
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
      printf("\t %2i. column %2i. row: ", i+1, j+1);
      scanf("%s", &feld[i][j]);
    }
  }
  for(j=0; j<3; j++)
  {
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
      printf("\t %c", feld[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: char data cells can only store one character thus being called char...if you try to write "xx" to a char it will overflow into the next memory cell...plus that is just the nature of `scanf` (with `%s` as the first argument) to write all cells from the input to the output

Answer (score 2):

With this line:

```
scanf("%s", &feld[i][j]);
```

you are reading a string (multiple characters) and placing them where should only be one character. 
This will cause damage to characters that are stored nearby.
Use something like:

```
scanf("%c", &feld[i][j]);
```

to read only one character each time around. 
But this solution is not perfect either, because now if you feed too many character they will remain stored until you try to read them again, which results in some odd behaviour, like printing multiple times without waiting for your inputs:

```
2. column 1. row:     3. column 1. row:     1. column 2. row:
```

The correct answer depends on what you want to happen if you feed multiple inputs at once.

Comment: THANK YOU, for including the bit at the end on `scanf` having leftover data. Saves another duplicate question following this one. :)

Answer (score 1):

Below is the working code. Each element in the array is a character. `%s` is used to scan a string not a character. You need to use `%c`. Add space before `%c` for scanf to eat/gobble whitespaces and special characters.(like enter)

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
int i,j;
char feld[3][3];
for(j=0; j<3; j++)
{
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("\t %2i. Row %2i. Column:\n ", j+1, i+1);
        scanf(" %c", &feld[j][i]);
}
}
for(j=0; j<3; j++)
{
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("\t%c", feld[j][i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem! Can you explain to me, why the space gobbles up the whitespaces?

Answer (score 0):

First of all in your code 'j' is representing row so it should be first and i should be after like feld[j][i]
And second in char size is 1 so we can store single char only that is why it problem by use more then one input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
int i,j;
char feld[3][3];
for(j=0; j<3; j++)
{
for(i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    printf("\t %2i. column %2i. row: ", i+1, j+1);
    scanf("%c", &feld[j][i]);
}
}
for(j=0; j<3; j++)
{
for(i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    printf("\t %c", feld[i][j]);
}
printf("\n");
```

}
    }